# Varnish 4 VCL - remove all cookies & varnishlog watching

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Ok, so I'm currently devving a box with Varnish 4 and I'm curious what a normal (although if all online examples are any indication it's stripping out known cookies only) cookie approach is? Is it stripping out all cookies and white-listing known cookies? That seems a little more sensible, so that's what I'm curious of. After looking at https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRemovingSomeCookies the very bottom they show how to remove all but SOME (white-listing) and then directly under the headline say (warning - not pretty).

Here's the snippet:

```
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.http.Cookie) {
set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(COOKIE1|COOKIE2)=", "; \1=");
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
    remove req.http.Cookie;
}
}
```

Firstly, did someone just throw that (warning - not pretty) part because it's not really the optimal setup or in the sense of "hey this is going to be a nightmare trying to take user reports on" or something?

The second thing I'm curious of (reassurance! :P), that will literally strip out any and all cookies outside of one names COOKIE1|COOKIE2, correct?

And the last thing I'm curious of about that snippet, where COOKIE1|COOKIE2 is, (I don't know regex very well) does that mean I can replace COOKIE1 with say __bilbobaggins (real cookie name __bilbobaggins=1;134;onewasaring) and then COOKIE2 with  1_2_3__4_cookiename (real cookie name 1_2_3__4_cookiename=this,is,another,cookie) and it will allow those all through without any need for regexes or something for the actual cookie data to pass?

I'm sadly not thinking it's as simple as that though?

---

Also, regardless of the above approach is there any Varnish 4 varnishlog syntax I can use to monitor ONLY cookies that are hitting the back-end?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question I'd say it's more about readability than performance. If you understand the code and you are comfortable with it I don't see any issues.

The answer to your second question is yes, it will keep COOKIE1 and COOKIE2. You can verify that using varnishtest. Please note that you need to rename "remove" to "unset" (remove is Varnish 3 specific).

Regarding the last question, correct, you can replace COOKIE1 and COOKIE2 with the name of the real cookies. Just have in mind that you need to encode ";".

For a different approach check the cookie vmod at https://github.com/lkarsten/libvmod-cookie.

As for varnishlog, you could use:

`varnishlog -I BereqHeader:^Cookie`

Comment: When you say "encode ';'" what exactly do you mean? I can't just replace `(COOKIE1|...)` with `(_ga|COOKIE2)` and it will allow any cookie with _ga to hit the backend? Let's also take WordPress as a real example, if I used that above code it will strip out all cookies so they don't hit the backend and Varnish will cache it, but can I use regex in the (COOKIE1|...) part so I can do: `(wp-settings-[0-9]*|COOKIE2)` and the cookie `wp-settings-953=blahblahblah12388,203992,X00;` (note the numbers before the =) would be allowed through and obviously Varnish wouldn't cache it?

Comment: Currently I have `set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-[0-9]*=[^;]+(; )?", "");` and from the looks of things that's removing that cookie name I mentioned above, but like I said I don't know if regex is allowed in this approach.